# Missing Classes in XCode/Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, healthkit

In a Swift project I have the line

```
import HealthKit
```

Command Click opens a list of imports.

Command Click on any of these classes opens more.

**Except:** Command Click on

```
import HealthKit.HKWorkoutSession
```

opens an empty file.

This corresponds to compiler error messages **HKWorkoutSession is unavailable** and **HKWorkoutSessionLocationType is unavailable** in my code.

This started in XCode 7 beta 3 after using it a while. Moving to XCode 7 beta 4 didn't change anything. Cleaning the project doesn't change anything.

I suspect this has nothing to do with HealthKit but with some missing files. 
So any idea how I can reinstall the HealthKit development files when installing a new XCode don't help? Or any other fix?

**Edit:**

[image: Missing Class]

Comment: You don't need `import HealthKit.HKWorkoutSession`. just import `HealthKit` and use it, try to delete DerivedData and reopen Xcode

Comment: I do not import HealthKit.HKWorkoutSession. I only described what I see when I Command click on "HealthKit" in "import HealthKit"

Comment: This code works in playground. It show error to console that HKWorkout can't be created by it there is no Xcode error

`import HealthKit
let sample = HKWorkout()`

Comment: HKWorkoutSession is available only for WatchOS, are you using it in WathcOS target ?

Comment: That's it! Thanks :-) Was searching in a completely wrong direction. If you write this as an answer, I can give you the deserved credit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  `HKWorkoutSession` is available only in watchOS.  Make sure you using in in the watchOS target.

Here is [HKWorkoutSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkoutSession_ClassReference/index.html) documentation. Check the availability label when using it.
[image]